# Is there any reason to use XML/XSLT when using a PHP/MySQL App?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xslt

I have been making HTML/PHP/MySQL database apps for quite a while now.  I have avoided using XML/XSLT in any application since I just pull the data out and format it within my PHP script, and display it.

Assuming I am not wanting my data to be portable to other people's applications (via XML), is there any reason to implement an XML/XSLT based web app or is it a matter of preference?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of preference.

XML/XSLT are useful when transforming XML to multiple other XML formats (rss, xhtml etc...), so if you don't need this kind of functionality, don't go with it.

They also add a cost in complexity and processing power. Again, if you don't need it, don't use them.

Answer (score 1):

I use XML/XSLT as a template engine.

Througout my script, I gather my data as nodes and put them in an XML object. When I need to display data, I feed this XML object to an XSLT and display the result.